# How to efficiently block text with a font colour?

Tags: latex, pdflatex

How can I make this markdown code for blocking text with a font colour applied?

I am beginner to markdown and I have applied the code below and it works, but is there a more efficient way of doing without repeating \textcolor{blue}{....} and >?

> 

\textcolor{blue}{rm(A)}

> 

\textcolor{blue}{rm(B,C)}

> 

\textcolor{blue}{rm(A)}

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new command for color blue

```
\newcommand\blue[1]{{\color{blue}#1}}
```

Everytime you need to change the text color to blue, you just type

```
\blue{some text}
```

Comment: Any resources you would recommend for doing markdown for PDF format?